# Generating a table of given dimensions

Tags: javascript, css-tables

I'm trying to generate a table consisting of the highest possible number of square cells of given dimensions. The difficult part is, that the table must not exceed the viewport dimensions. The CSS of the table is as follows:

```
.gameField {
  table-layout: fixed;
  position:  absolute;
  top: 0px; left: 0px;
  border-spacing: 1px 1px;
}
```

And it has a html attribute **cellSpacing = "1"** as a fallback for the *border-spacing* non-compilant browsers. Now, my code is based on the following assumption:

```
viewPortWidth  = numberOfColumns * cellSideLength + (numberOfColumns + 1)
viewPortHeight = numberOfRows    * cellSideLength + (numberOfRows    + 1)
```

To explain a bit on the logic behind - the length of a side of the table consists always of the number of cells * the length of their side + the borders. And there is always one border more than the number of rows / columns, thus *(numberOfColumns or Rows + 1)*. Treating this as a mathematical equation, we, knowing the *cellSideLength* and viewport dimensions, can easily calculate the number of rows and columns:

```
numberOfColumns = Math.floor( (viewportWidth  - 1) / (cellSideLength + 1) )
numberOfRows    = Math.floor( (viewportHeight - 1) / (cellSideLength + 1) )
```

The problem, however, is that it doesn't seem to work properly. The table appears to be a bit smaller than it could be on small resolutions and gets a bit too large on hight resolutions and exceeds the page (I tested that via zooming the page off - that may not be too accurate a test). - ***[Live demonstration](http://deltak.ic.cz/showcase/)*** *(cellSideLength set to 40px)* - You can zoom the page off for example in Chromium and see how the table exceeds the page.

That makes me think that maybe my assumptions as to how the size of a html table is determined were a bit off. If anyone has any useful advice, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining the ViewPort width is dependent upon on the browser.  See http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/ for more details.

Also, in CSS3 the unit 'vw' (viewport width) can used:

```
 .gameField { table-layout: fixed; width: 1vw }
```

Comment: Well, I use my own lib for obtaining the viewPort dimensions and it appears to work just fine, so that's not the problem. :-) Also I use Math.floor() in my code as shown in the OP -> the table will be as big as the viewport or smaller (or at least that's the plan, it doesn't exactly work - see the OP), so there is no point in hardcoding the width of the table in the CSS. But I didn't know about the vw unit in CSS3, thank you for bringing that up. :-)